# PHP escapeshellarg() doesn't work

Tags: php, encryption

On the first `shell_exec()` I encrypt a message and on the second `shell_exec()` I want to decrypt my cypher. Encrypt and decrypt functions work well. It seems that first `shell_exec()` returns a data type that can't be used as a variable in the second `shell_exec()`. What can I do?

```
<?php
 $plaintext = "unpuzzle";
 echo '<p>'.$plaintext.'</p>';
 $criptotext = shell_exec('java DES '. escapeshellarg($plaintext) .' 1');
 echo '<p>Criptotext: ' . $criptotext . '</p>';
 $plaintext = shell_exec('java DES '. escapeshellarg($criptotext) .' 2');
 echo '<p>Plaintext: ' . $plaintext . '</p>';
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($criptotext)` show?

Comment: string(17) "4DC4B9F5CF6ACF46 "

Comment: it seems that I get a space character after my cypher and because of that decrypt function won't work...

Comment: I used trim() to solve the problem, thanks for the observation! Do you know why I get that space character because it's not from my java class.

Comment: I explained it in the answer. It's a newline, not a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shell_exec` returns the output from the command, which includes the newline at the end. You need to remove the newline before using this as the cryptotext.

```
$criptotext = rtrim(shell_exec('java DES ' . escapeshellarg($plaintext) . ' 1'), "\r\n");
```